# Collapsing if statements when more than one condition is anded

Tags: c#

Is there any way to collapse this into one if condition, or just one return statement?

```
     public bool SomethingEnabled
     {
            if (!condition1)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return condition2
                && (condition3 || !condition4);
      }
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Certainly you're not under the misguided notion that fewer lines of code => faster execution times, right?

Comment: @Cody - Next you'll be telling people that there is no santa claus.

Answer (score 7):

This is equivalent:

```
public bool SomethingEnabled
{
    return condition1 && condition2 && (condition3 || !condition4);
}
```

but in the interest of readability and maintainability, I would strongly caution against writing code that's too clever.

Comment: I don't think you need extra parenthesis around `(condition2 && .. )`

Comment: I think it is fair to grant the answer to 'trutheality'. He was the first with the shortest implementation.

Comment: I suppose I didn't make it clear (at all), that I want to bail out, if condition 1 is false. Is that possible?

Comment: @gurunakka kamelseh - you can't remove condition1 without changing the result.

Comment: @gurunakka that will already happen due to [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Comment: @gurunakka if cond1 is false, then the whole condition will evaluate to false. I'm not very familiar with c#, but in many languages if cond1 is false, the rest will not be even evaluated, since it can only return false.

Answer (score 2):

```
return condition1 && condition2 && (condition3 || !condition4);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
return condition1 && (condition2 && (condition3 || !condition4));
```

The first condition is to return false if condition1 is false. The condition will evaluate to false altogether if condition1 is false. If it's true, it evaluates to whatever the rest does.

Comment: @Matt I type slow and with typos. What can I say :P

Answer (score 1):

Better names and small functions would help:

```
public bool SomethingEnabled
{
   if (IsInvalid) return false;

   return IsInReadyState && IsInOtherState;
}

public bool IsInvalid
{
   return !condition1;
}

public bool IsInReadyState
{
   return condition3 || !condition4;
}

public bool IsInOtherState
{
   return condition2;
}
```

Comment: Nice sentiment. `IsValid` would make for more readable code than `IsInvalid` (consider when they're combined with `!`). Also `SomethingEnabled` could be simplified further.

Comment: @Johnysweb - Yea, the lack of context made it difficult to show what I wanted to show.

Comment: Yes, yes, a thousand times yes! Readability over cleverness.